# Disable rendering ng-view until data is downloaded

Tags: dom, angularjs, angular-template

I use both server side templates and angular ones. When page is opened for the first time it contains `<div ng-view>` containing rendered page. Then angular starts, Firstly showing empty template then downloading data and showing same thing as at the beginging.

How to disable angular.js rendering not to modify DOM until data is downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to accomplish, you can use either [ngCloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak) or [ngBind](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBind).